# Binding to object not property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, object, properties

While using a converter, I want to bind to the entire object and send it to the converter to use, rather than binding to each of the individual properties, so I can do this:

```
Order thisOrder = (Order)values[0];
```

(note, its a multibinding, other values are being sent in besides the thisOrder object. Now the Order class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and raised the appropriate events when any of its properties are changed. The converter needs access to multiple properties of the Order, although it actually only needs to rerun on changes to one of the properties. Is there any way to either bind to the entire object so that if any of the properties change, the converter is evaluated again, or bind to only one property, but have the rest of the object also available as a parameter for the converter to work on?

> Example Details: 
>   Order has following fields:
>
> - ID
> - MarketPrice
> - Name
>
> When MarketPrice changes, the converter needs to recalculate based on
>   ID and MarketPrice.
>   Presently, the binding is applied on the DataRecordCellArea of a xamDataGrid, as follows:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MarketPositionToBrushConverter}">
     <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Record.DataItem"/>
...
</MultiBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there currently is no clean solution to this. I would suggest you add two bindings, one to the `Order` object so you have access to all the values and another to the `MarketPrice` so that the binding updates if that property changes. You then have access to the object and all properties via the first binding and you get the respective updates.

The is another method which is quite a hack, you can subscribe to `PropertyChanged` in the class owning the `Order` instance and then fire a change notification for the `Order` instance property whenever the `MarketPrice` in the instance changes. I would avoid doing this but it would allow you to get rid of the second binding.

Comment: Wish I'd thought of the first method! While from a theoretical point of view it makes me cringe, on a practical level its an easy way to get things done. I'll wait another couple of days to see if a less hackish solution comes up, otherwise I'll implement this.

Comment: its annoying that you can't just bind the entire object then do .isenabled vs having to bind every property individually.  So much extra work and code.

Comment: how about having a property in you Order object of type Object that hold reference to it self ?

Comment: @IronHide: Usually the issue is getting the correct change notifications, which you will not get just by adding such a property.